# Symfony choice form with months only

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to create form in Symfony with select field filled by months only.

i have something like that:

```
$builder
        ->add('month','date', array(
            'widget' => 'choice',
        ));
```

I got day | month | years selects.

Why i need it?

I want select month and after press button i want to get data from database only ranged by selected month.
I need months dictionary or calendar in database? Entity?
How to get date from this select to repository function?

@edit And how to display months in other language than English?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Define your own custom `MonthChoiceType` :

```
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MonthChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'label' => 'choose month',
            'choices' => $this->getChoices()
        ));
    }

    protected function getChoices()
    {
        $choices = array(
            'January'   => 1,
            'February'  => 1,
            'March'     => 1,
            'April'     => 1,
            'May'       => 1,
            'June'      => 1,
            'July'      => 1,
            'August'    => 1,
            'September' => 1,
            'October'   => 1,
            'November'  => 1,
            'December'  => 1,
        );

        return $choices;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```

## 2. Use it inside your form:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Form\MonthChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('month', MonthChoiceType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```